# How to declare useState() initial value as null and then give it an object value later?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-state

[image]

As can be seen in the image, I want to declare a react state hook to the alert of my webpage. At first, I want that there is no alert shown. And whenever user is clicking some button, I want to show a success alert with a message (error alert if something goes wrong). I will call showAlert function to do this with message and type as function parameter. That's why there can be more than one type of alert. So, I created this alert object and attached hook with initial value "NULL". But the editor gives me this error.

```
Argument of type '{ msg: any; type: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<null>'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'msg' does not exist in type '(prevState: null) => null'.ts(2345)
```

So, can someone tell me how I can tell useState the object parameters that I will allot it in future. Or should I try to hide the website alert in some other way? Here is the code..

```
const [alert, setAlert] = useState(null);

const showAlert = (message, type) => {
    setAlert({
        msg: message,
        type: type,
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
        setAlert(null);
    }, 2000);
```

[image]

This solution is not working for me.

Comment: Please replace the image of code with a text-based [mcve]

Comment: Define the type of the state `useState(null as any)`

Comment: `useState<{msg: string, type: string}>(null)`. In case if you have strict null checks on in your tsconfig, you will not able to set null. Either you can remove that from tsconfig or you can `useState<{msg: string, type: string} | null>(null)`

Comment: @Rashomon I have tried that. I get these two erros.
1. Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," (10:41)eslint {squigly error on null word}
2. Type assertion expressions can only be used in TypeScript files.ts(8016) {error line under any word}

Comment: @Dilshan I am getting these errors for your solution.
1. Type 'number' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.ts(2488)
2. (property) msg: any
Operator '<' cannot be applied to types '{ <S>(initialState: S | (() => S)): [S, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>]; <S = undefined>(): [S | undefined, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S | undefined>>]; }' and '{ msg: any; type: any; }'.ts(2365)
The '|' operator is not allowed for boolean types. Consider using '||' instead.ts(2447)
3. Comparing to itself is potentially pointless.eslintno-self-compare
Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)

Answer (score 4):

From the looks of the error you mentioned, it seems you're using TypeScript.

One way to achieve the desired outcome is to use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#handbook-content).

```
const [alert, setAlert] = useState<{
  msg: string;
  type: "success" | "error";
} | null>(null);
```

Furthermore, you can improve readability by adding an [enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#handbook-content) and a type.

```
enum AlertType {
  Success,
  Error,
}

type Alert = {
  msg: string;
  type: AlertType;
}

const [alert, setAlert] = useState<Alert | null>(null);
```

Comment: I am using javascript only but it seems like I am getting typesript errors in javascript. Also the solution you gave will not work because type aliases and enum declarations aren't supported in javascript.

Comment: I've assumed that you're using TypeScript, hence the nature of the solution.
You are correct, this will not work in a JavaScript context.

@BittuJoshi , it seems that VSCode has implicit TS validation even for JS files.
You can give [this one a try](https://medium.com/lessons-from-debugging/remove-ts-errors-from-js-files-3970d1a5336c).

Answer (score 3):

You can do it below way for useState type

```
type AlertType = {
 msg: string;
 type: string; // you can specify enum also
}

const [alert, setAlert] = useState<AlertType|null>(null);

const showAlert = (message, type) => {
    setAlert({
        msg: message,
        type: type,
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
        setAlert(null);
    }, 2000);
```

Comment: 'AlertType' is declared but never used.ts(6196)
Type aliases can only be used in TypeScript files.ts(8008)

I am using javascript

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare your useState a little differently

```
const [alert, setAlert] = useState<{ msg: any; type: any } | null>(null);
```

Another alternative is the use `undefined`

```
const [alert, setAlert] = useState<{ msg: any; type: any } | undefined>();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Operator '<' cannot be applied to types '{ <S>(initialState: S | (() => S)): [S, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>]; <S = undefined>(): [S | undefined, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S | undefined>>]; }' and '{ msg: any; type: any; }'.ts(2365)
----The '|' operator is not allowed for boolean types. Consider using '||' instead.ts(2447)
----'any' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)-----Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 solutions:

```
1: useState(null as any)
2: useState({ msg: any, type: any })
```

Comment: 1. Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," (10:41)eslint {error line under null} 
 and
Type assertion expressions can only be used in TypeScript files.ts(8016) {error line under any}

2. 'any' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)
'any' is not defined.eslintno-undef